# Resize UIImage Keep Image Quality in Swift

Tags: swift, image, resize, blurry

I have created an image from UIView using UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext. It's work fine but when I resized that image to larger size its be blurred with bad quality. Can it possibility to keep quality when resize? I have tried many ways but not work. 
 - code image:

```
func image(with view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.isOpaque, 0.0)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

        context.setAllowsAntialiasing(true)
        context.setShouldAntialias(true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        return image

    }
    return nil
```

}

code I have used to resize, this extension of UIImage

```
func resizedImage(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    // Guard newSize is different
    guard self.size != newSize else { return self }
     let aspect_ratio = self.size.width / self.size.height

    var image_w = newSize.height * aspect_ratio

    let finalSize = CGSize(width: image_w, height: newSize.height) 
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(finalSize, false, 0.0)
    self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (CGFloat)(finalSize.width), height: (CGFloat)(newSize.height)))
    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

and the example image:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVgRh.png)
Thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but we don’t use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` any more. We use [`UIGraphicsImageRenderer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicsimagerenderer). See [Image and Graphics Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/219/) for more info. But this is unrelated to the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
extension UIImage {
    func resizeImage(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let size = self.size
        let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / size.width
        let heightRatio = targetSize.height / size.height
        let newSize = widthRatio > heightRatio ?  CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio) : CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio,  height: size.height * widthRatio)
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
        self.draw(in: rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
  }
}
```

Comment: Doens't work man